# What is the status of AMD graphics card drivers in Ubuntu 16.04/16.10?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics, 16.10

As far  as I know there are `amdgpu` and `fglrx` AMD drivers and foss `radeon` driver. Where can I find a list what driver supports which card, which X.Org server, which Ubuntu vesion (16.04 and 16.10)?

Is there a new proprietary AMD driver instead of fglrx?

*Although my question has been identified as a possible duplicate and I foud there a partial answer to my question, it didn't give me a list of supported amdgpu-pro models and also amdgpu supported models. I think this list should exist so we can buy compatible Ubuntu hardware.